# Can I build a model with Paperclip attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a model `Style` which has a paperclip attachment `file`. I am using a multi-page form for creating the `Style`s. In my first step I upload the `file` and in the next page I update the other attributes of the `Style` record. I don't know how to build the style with the attachment so that it can be used in the later step.

Below is my action for my second step. The attachment `file` is not yet saved, so how do I build it that the file is available in the view. Any help is appreciated.

```
def build_form
  styles = params_array.delete(:styles)
  @styles = []
  styles.each do |style_file|
    name = style_file.original_filename.split(".")[0..-2].join(".")
    @styles << Style.new(name: name, file: style_file)
  end
  render :new
end
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is stateless so if your multipage form is using HTTP requests I think you should be able to save it to database or store in the session.
If you are saving it to the database you should remove record at the end if any step is not valid.
But I think multipage form should use js, so file content and file info is saved to the form.

So my suggestion is to use [ajax for multipage form](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27188/multi-page-form-with-each-step-loaded-via-ajax), in this case, you will have all content on the page, but some content would be hidden